# How can I insert a row when my trigger raises an exception? [Oracle SQL]

Tags: sql, oracle, exception, triggers

I'm trying to make a project, which is named "cards reservation" (for school) with APEX. It should work the same like in a cinema, there are a few shows and a user can reserve a seat for a special show.

Now I want to make a trigger, who verifies that there are not 2 shows at the same time in one room and between each show should be 15 mins.

It looks like this at the moment:

```
create or replace trigger tg_roomoccupancy
before insert or update on show
for each row
declare
  sDate date;
  sDuration number(4);
  newDuration number(4);
begin
  select datum into sDate from show where room = :new.room and to_char(datum, 'DD-MM-YYYY') = to_char(:new.datum, 'DD-MM-YYYY');
  select dauer into vDuration from film f, show s where to_char(datum, 'DD-MM-YYYY') = to_char(:new.datum, 'DD-MM-YYYY') AND s.filmId = f.filmId;
  select dauer into newDuration from film where film.filmId = :new.filmId;

  if((((:new.datum - sDate)*1440) < (sDuration + 15)) AND (((:new.datum - vDate)*1440) > 0))then
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'There is an other show running in this room!');
  elsif((((sDate - :new.datum)*1440) < (newDuration + 15)) AND ((sDate - :new.datum)*1440) > 0) then
    raise_application_error(-20002, 'The show lasts too long, an other show will start!');
  elsif((sDate - :new.datum) = 0) then
    raise_application_error(-20003, 'Two shows cannot start at the same time!');
  end if;
end;+
```

You can see, what the ifs are doing, I multiplicate with 1440, because the subtraction between two dates gives a number in days and i multiplicate this with *24*60 to get this difference in minutes, because the duration of a film is also given in minutes.

The trigger raises the errors as I want, but my problem is:

When I want to insert a show on a day, where no other show is running, I get a "NO_DATA_FOUND"-Exception and I can not insert the new show. How can I insert the new show?

Thanks for your help and sorry for bad english :-)

Comment: Hi
If NO_DATA_FOUND is really not a problem, then you could add an EXCEPTIONS clause for NO_DATA_FOUND which does NULL

Comment: You'll also get a too-many-rows error if the a film is being shown in the same room twice on the same day (say, screenings at 17:00 and 20:00), so you need to rethink how you're querying the data - consider using a cursor over all shows in that room, which would tackle both errors; or a single query that counts potential overlaps.

Comment: @AlexPoole: Well, I never recognized that... How would the code for that cursor look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply logic similar to this in trigger below.

Tables created with this code. You can add constraint on show.filmId checking movie existence in film table, 
but here it is done by trigger. I would also join two errors (2002 and 2003) into one and throw error 
"Another show running in this room or interval too short", but it is up to you.

```
create table show (datum date not null, room number not null, filmId number not null);
create table film (filmId number not null unique, dauer number not null);

insert into film values (1, 120);
```

Test:

```
insert into show (datum, room, filmId) values 
  (to_date('2015-01-01 15:00:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH24:mi:ss'), 1, 1);
=> OK  

insert into show (datum, room, filmId) values
  (to_date('2015-01-01 15:00:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH24:mi:ss'), 1, 2);
=> Incorrect movie ID.

insert into show (datum, room, filmId) values
  (to_date('2015-01-01 16:00:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH24:mi:ss'), 1, 1);
=> Another show running in this room.

insert into show (datum, room, filmId) values
  (to_date('2015-01-01 17:10:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH24:mi:ss'), 1, 1);
=> Interval between shows too short.

insert into show (datum, room, filmId) values
  (to_date('2015-01-01 17:20:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH24:mi:ss'), 1, 1);
=> OK.

insert into show (datum, room, filmId) values
  (to_date('2015-01-01 17:20:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH24:mi:ss'), 2, 1);
=> OK.  (Show is in another room.)
```

Trigger code:

```
create or replace trigger tg_roomoccupancy
before insert or update on show
for each row
declare
  v_duration number;
  v_cnt number;
begin

  begin 
    select dauer into v_duration
      from film f where filmId = :new.filmId;
  exception when no_data_found then
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'Incorrect movie ID.');
  end;

  select count(1) into v_cnt from show join film f using (filmId)
    where room = :new.room and 
      ((:new.datum between datum and datum + f.dauer/1440)
        or (:new.datum+v_duration/1440 between datum and datum + f.dauer/1440));
  if v_cnt > 0 then
    raise_application_error(-20002, 'Another show running in this room.');
  end if;

  select count(1) into v_cnt from show join film f using (filmId)
    where room = :new.room and 
      ((:new.datum between datum - 15/1440 and datum + (f.dauer + 15)/1440)
        or (:new.datum + v_duration/1440 
          between datum - 15/1440 and datum + (f.dauer+15)/1440));
  if v_cnt > 0 then
    raise_application_error(-20003, 'Interval between shows too short.');
  end if;

end;
```

Comment: nice one, thank you ;-)

the between method is nice, I completely forgot about that ^^

Comment: I noticed a bug. If you insert short movie starting at 15:00, ending 16:00 and then add long movie 14:00-17:00 trigger will not fire exception. Add proper correction to deal with this situation, it's small condition change.